'deducing' a bound using the first order taylor series. How to make it more precise?
So, I just saw a ‘proof’ that the generalized birthday problem has a median of C*sqrt(n). Though the probability in question is interesting, this question is more about calculus and maybe asymptotics than probability. I have a proof outline that I want to make more precise
The context:
Take
$$p_r = (n)_r/n^r$$
(this is meant to be the odds that, in a world with n days, where n >= 365, we get r people at random and none shares a birthday. $(n)_r = n!/(n-r)!$)
We can write p_r as $(1-1/n)\cdot(1-2/n)\cdot...(1-(r-1)/n)$
Now, I want to find the smallest r such that p_r > ½ (this is a median time for a birthday ‘collision’)
The ‘proof’ (I am trying to expand an argument from Feller’s An introduction to probability theory chap 2, section 2, around formula 7.4)
say
$$ ½ = p_r $$
take -log from both sides
-log(½) =  -log(p_r)
= -1(log(1-1/n)+log(1-2/n)+...log(1-(r-1)/n)
Using the taylor series for log(1-x)
f(0) + f’(0) * x/1! + error

log(1-x) = log(1) + f’(0) * x + error
f’(x) = 1/(1-x)*(-1) = (x-1)^(-1) => f’(0) = -1

log(1-x) = - x + error

So we get
-log(½) =  -log(p_r)
= -1(log(1-1/n)+log(1-2/n)+...log(1-(r-1)/n)
= -1(-1/n-2/n…-(r-1)/n)
= 1/n(r*(r-1)/2)
~= r^2/2n

Therefore
log(2) ~= r^2/2n
sqrt(2*n*log(2)) ~= r

The weird step for me is the ignoring of the taylor series error. I could bound it using the second derivative of log(1-x), but this would be tedious (I did try).
My question:
We did take the first term of the taylor series, did some calculations with it and got a result, with an unbounded error. What is an easy way to bound this error and know how reliable is the result?
In this question, I am more interested in techniques (if there are any) to easily bind the taylor series error than in other techniques to bypass the taylor series and solve the problem.
Question focus: The main goal of the question is to find a way to actually use the taylor expansion. Is there a precise and formal way to do so that is also easier than doing all the inequations with the second order error term?

@josinalvo ignoring the error (it is always positive) transforms the original inequality into another inequality. Once you obtain an estimate of $r$ this way, if you wan to show that it is the actual median, you should show that $r-1$ no longer satisfies the original inequality.

There is a birthday tag; did you want to add it?

Wikipedia suggests $\sqrt{2 \log_e(2)}\sqrt{n} + 0.26895 \lt r \lt \sqrt{2 \log_e(2)}\sqrt{n} + 1.27921$, which for most $n$ will give a single integer in that interval.

thanks @Henry, but the focus of the question is: how good of an estimate is $\sqrt(2ln(2))\sqrt(n)$ in the first place, given that the deduction we have for it is using the taylor series without much care?

@josinalvo to which the answer is "excellent".  The median is always either $\sqrt{2 \log_e(2)}\sqrt{n}$ rounded up to the next integer, or (in nearly $27%$ of cases) $1$ more than that.

You could write the Taylor expansion of
\begin{align*} 
g(x) &:= \ln\left((1-0x/n) (1-x/n) (1-2x/n) \dots (1-(r-1)x/n)\right) \\\\
&= \ln(1-x/n) + \dots + \ln(1-(r-1)x/n) . 
\end{align*}
We have $g(0) = 0$, $g’(0) = -1/n - \dots - (r-1)/n = -r(r-1)/(2n)$, and
$$g’’(x) = -\frac{1}{(1-x/n)^2} - \dots - \frac{(r-1)^2}{(1-(r-1)x/n)^2} , $$
so that $|g’’(x)| \leq \frac{r(r-1)^2}{(1-(r-1)/n)^2}$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. We can then use the known bounds on the remainder in a Taylor expansion to get
$$ |g(1) - g(0) - g’(0)| \leq \frac{r(r-1)^2}{2(1-(r-1)/n)^2} . $$
Assuming $r\leq n/2$, this simplifies to
$$ \left|\ln p_r + \frac{r(r-1)}{2n}\right| \leq \frac{2r^3}{n^2} . $$

The first step is to not use Taylor series but to use a powerful technique called smoothing. This technique is heuristic; the more creative you are, the stronger results you may be able to obtain using it. For bounding the relevant probability for the birthday problem, the following smoothing suffices:
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$
  $a·b ≥ (a-t)·(b+t)$ for every $a,b,t∈ℝ^+$ such that $a ≤ b$.
Using this alone, we can pair up the terms in the product (first with last and so on) and obtain both lower bound and upper bound for them:
  $1·(1-\lfrac{r}{n}) ≤ (1-\lfrac{k}{n})·(1-\lfrac{r-k}{n}) ≤ (1-\lfrac{r}{2n})^2$
It is now easy to obtain explicit bounds on the original product:
  $(1-\lfrac{r}{n})^{(r-1)/2} ≤ p_r ≤ (1-\lfrac{r}{2n})^{r-1}$.
You can now employ explicit inequalities for $\exp,\ln$:
  $1+x ≤ \exp(x)$ for every $x∈ℝ$.
  $x-x^2 ≤ \ln(1+x)$ for every $x∈ℝ_{≥-1/2}$.
To get for $r ≤ \lfrac12 n$:
  $\exp(\lfrac{r-1}{2}{·}(-\lfrac{r}{n}-\lfrac{r^2}{n^2})) ≤ p_r ≤ \exp(-\lfrac{r}{2n})^{r-1}$.
You can hence bound $p_r$ within a factor of $\exp(-\lfrac{(r-1)·r^2}{2n^2}) ≈ 1$ for $r^3 ≪ n^2$. For large $n$, we have $√(2n)^3 ≪ n^2$ and so the error factor tends to $1$ for the $r$ that makes $p_r$ closest to $\lfrac12$.

Thank you, this answer made me learn a lot.

@Seno: Thank you for your comment too! Feel free to ask me anything more! =)

This is more a comment
on the derivation of the series
but is too long for a comment
and I thought it worthwhile.
Here is my favorite way
to get the partial sums
of the series for
$\log(1+x)$
(natural log)
and show that
the sums are enveloping
(alternate sums are
above and below).
This, of course,
is not original,
but is,
in my opinion,
useful enough
and comes up in enough questions
(such as this one)
to bear repeating.
$\sum_{k=0}^m t^k
=\dfrac{1-t^{m+1}}{1-t}
=\dfrac{1}{1-t}-\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{1-t}
$
so
$\dfrac{1}{1-t}
=\sum_{k=0}^m t^k+\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{1-t}
$.
Putting $-t$ for $t$,
$\frac{1}{1+t}
=\sum_{k=0}^m (-t)^k+\frac{(-1)^{m+1}t^{m+1}}{1+t}
$.
Integrating from $0$ to $x$,
$\begin{array}\\
\log(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\int_0^x (\sum_{k=0}^m (-t)^k)dt+\int_0^x \dfrac{dt(-1)^{m+1}t^{m+1}}{1+t}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\int_0^xt^kdt+(-1)^{m+1}\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+(-1)^{m+1}\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+(-1)^{m+1}e_m(x)\\
\end{array}
$
where
$e_m(x)=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}$.
Since
$e_m(x) > 0$
for $x > 0$,
$$\log(1+x)
-\sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}
=(-1)^{2m+1}e_{2m}(x)
=-e_{2m}(x)
\lt 0$$
and
$$\log(1+x)
-\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}
=(-1)^{2m+2}e_{2m+1}(x)
=e_{2m+1}(x)
\gt 0$$
Also note that
$\begin{array}\\
e_m(x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&<\int_0^x t^{m+1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^{m+2}}{m+2}\\
\text{and}\\
e_m(x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+t}\\
&>\int_0^x \dfrac{t^{m+1}dt}{1+x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{m+2}}{(m+2)(1+x)}\\
\end{array}
$
